# Is $\mathbb{B}(H) \bigotimes \mathbb{B}(H)$ never equal to $\mathbb{B}(H\bigotimes H)$

Tags: operator-theory, tensor-products, operator-algebras

Given a Hilbert space $H$, if we use $\mathbb{B}(H)\bigodot\mathbb{B}(H)$ to denote the tensor product before taking the spatial norm closure, then we will have $\mathbb{B}(H)\bigodot\mathbb{B}(H)$ is dense in $\mathbb{B}(H\bigotimes H)$ in weak operator topology because $\mathbb{B}(H)\bigodot\mathbb{B}(H)$ contains all finite rank operators defined in $H\bigotimes H$. My question is:

1. If $H$ is infinite dimensional, is it true that $\mathbb{B}(H)\bigodot\mathbb{B}(H)$ is **never** dense in $\mathbb{B}(H\bigotimes H)$ in norm (or will $\mathbb{B}(H)\bigotimes\mathbb{B}(H)$ be always properly contained in $\mathbb{B}(H\bigotimes H))$?
2. If $H$ is finite dimensional, what will be the answer in question 1? In general, is it true that $M_n(\mathbb{C})\bigotimes M_m(\mathbb{C})$ is never equal to $M_{mn}(\mathbb{C})$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to question (1) is no.  In case $H$ is a separable Hilbert
space there are many significant differences between $B(H\otimes H)$ and the (spacial)
tensor product $B(H)\otimes B(H)$.  The former has a unique closed
two-sided ideal, namely $K(H\otimes H)$ (compact operators), while the latter
has at least three, namely $K(H)\otimes K(H)$, $K(H)\otimes B(H)$, and $B(H)\otimes K(H)$.

For non-separable Hilbert spaces, the situation is similar.
Luft [1] has classified all closed ideals of $B(H)$, for an arbitrary Hilbert space
$H$, and, in particular, he has shown that these  ideals  form a
chain, meaning that for any two such ideals $I$ and $J$,  either $I\subseteq J$
or $J\subseteq I$.  On the other hand, in $B(H)\otimes B(H)$ the
ideal $I=K(H)\otimes B(H)$ neither contains nor is contained in the
ideal $J=B(H)\otimes K(H)$.

This actually  shows that $B(H)\otimes B(H)$ not only differs from
$B(H\otimes H)$, but these algebras are not even isomorphic.

In the finite dimensional context of (2) the situation is rather
different:  $M_n({\mathbb C})\otimes M_m({\mathbb C})$ is canonically isomorphic to  $M_{nm}({\mathbb C})$ (rather than $M_{n+m}({\mathbb C})$, as observed by Peter) and this can be easily checked by defining a natural map and showing it
to be an isomorphism by computing dimensions.

[1] *Luft, E.*, [**The two-sided closed ideals of the algebra of bounded linear operators of a Hilbert space**](https://eudml.org/doc/12436), Czech. Math. J. 18(93), 595-605 (1968). [ZBL0197.11301](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0197.11301).

Comment: Peter, you are totally correct.  I  fixed my answer to account for this.

Comment: @peterag Thank you for your correction. I just editted the question

Comment: @Ruy Thank you for your answers! Also, the paper you quoted is very helpful

Comment: I'm deleting my comments as even the original question has been updated (and +1, of course, esp. for the reference)